# How can I enable App Sandboxing for specific build configuration

Tags: xcode, app-store, xcode5, sandbox, buildconfiguration

I'm developing a Mac app, and preparing submit it to Mac AppStore.

I want distribute it on my website too, at the same time.

Since I use **Sparkle framework** to manage updates for the version outside AppStore, the app can **NOT** be sandboxed.

I know I can done this with multiple build targets, but keey two targets in sync is too heavy, since the only different is sandbox or not.

So I create a build configuration, and my configurations list like this:

- **Debug** : for development, Sandbox Disabled
- **Release** : for distributing outside Mac AppStore, Sandbox Disabled
- **MacAppStore** : for distributing to Mac AppStore, Sandbox Enabled

How can I enable Sandbox only for **MacAppStore** configuration?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

provide custom entitlement files for each build configuration. sandboxing is just a capability AFAIK.

entitlements file is a build setting and build settings can vary based on configuration

see screenshots for explanation

1. shows where to manage configs.
2. shows how I cleared the build setting for Release but left it for Appstore

[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you explain how to provide custom entitlement file for build configuration? I enabled App Sandbox in Capabilities, and Xcode add an .entitlement file to my project, how can I remove this file for Release configuration?

Comment: so use the capabilities page as normal and then see that xcode generates entitlements and sets those via the build setting 'code signing entitlements'

Comment: expand a build setting (triangle on the left of the setting) and modify it per config

Comment: don't forget that you'll likely have to clean build to get rid of old entitlements